# Loading bytes into C string by reference

Tags: c, byte, arrays

I am trying assign byte values of `0x00` to `0xff` to a C string with a function, and also report a length of the generated string. I am trying to get headed in the right direction, but seem to be stuck on a rather frustrating problem.

The code below shows my attempt to load byte values into the variable (passed by reference) `charset`. The code compiles and runs, but outputs nothing. However if I uncomment the second line in the `loadCharset` for loop, it will print all the desired values. I seem to be missing something on how to assign these values to the C string.

```
int loadCharset(int setname, char charset[], int *setlen){ //string sName){
    for (int i = 0x00; i <= 0xff; i++){
        charset[i] = i;
        // printf("%c", i);
    }
    // *setlen = 256;
}

int main() {
    char charset[256];
    int* setlen;
    loadCharset(1, charset, setlen);
    printf("%s", charset); // yields no output
}
```

Comment: The first character value in charset is 0, so printf will stop printing the "string" immediately. Try printing the values in a loop, or at least skip the first (0) element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of the `charset` array is `0x00`, which is the string terminator, telling `printf` to stop there -- without printing anything. Replace `printf` with:

```
fwrite(charset, sizeof (charset), 1, stdout);
```

which allows you specify the lenght of the array being printed explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

**Anticipating your next question:**

As soon as you uncomment `// *setlen = 256;` you will run into trouble.

This is what you want :

```
int main() {
    char charset[256];
    int setlen;
    loadCharset(1, charset, &setlen);
    printf("%s", charset); // yields no output
}
```

Note the `&` before `setlen`. And there is no more `*` before setlen in the declaration.